# How to pass in Latitude and Longitude parameters Yelp API

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the Yelp API and this is the search method:

```
func searchWithTerm(term: String, success: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void, failure: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {
        // For additional parameters, see http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api
        var parameters = ["term": term, "ll": "37.77493,-122.419415"]
        return self.GET("search", parameters: parameters, success: success, failure: failure)
    }
```

This is currently hardcoded with the given ll parameter. I have a the user's location stored in a different VC and when i try to pass in the lat and long to replace the hardcoded values, I get errors...

I store the location in my main ViewController as a CLLocationCoordinate2D. I want to then change the coordinates in the searchWithTermMethod

What am i doing wrong? It should be rather simple to pass in a value of double...

I try to do this:

```
func searchWithTerm(term: String, success: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void, failure: (AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {
            // For additional parameters, see http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api
            var parameters = ["term": term, "ll": userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude]
            return self.GET("search", parameters: parameters, success: success, failure: failure)
        }
```

and the error: "Expected ':' in dictionary literal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine latitude and longitude into a single string, you can use interpolation to do so:

```
var parameters = ["term": term, "ll": "\(userLocation.latitude), \(userLocation.longitude)"]
```